# Grouping and summing Cells based on MATCH criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, match, grouping

as an example I have created a small set of Data in B3:F20 with component, type and count list etc. I have assigned a Name "TypeP" for B24:B25.
[image: Group_List]

My goal is to group the components based on the type and sum their count from Input B3:F20. To show the final goal, I have manually added the result in L3:N7. In L4, multiple(here 2) instances of Component DEF with same type PA are grouped and the count is summed.

I was able to achieve my goal partially as in H3:J11, where the data was grouped based on the TypeP, but still I should be able to group the similar types.
Formula I have used in H3 is

=FILTER(INDEX(B3:F20;SEQUENCE(ROWS(B3:F20));{1\2\3});(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C3:C20;TypeP;0))=TRUE))

How can I achieve the result as shown in L3:N7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L3: =UNIQUE(H3:I11)
N3: =SUMIFS($J$3:$J$11,$H$3:$H$11,L3,$I$3:$I$11,M3)
```

Select `N3` and fill down as far as needed.

[image]

***You could also do this in Power Query***

To use Power Query

- Make your `TypeP` a Named Range (or a Table)
- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read main table
//Change table name in next line to real name of your table in the workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Component", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Count", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Others1", type text}, {"Others2", type any}}),

//read in the types to filter by from a "Named Range"
//  Range name is `TypeP` in the workbook
    typeP = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TypeP"]}[Content][Column1],

//Filter for the desired types
    filter = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(typeP,[Type])),

//Group by "component and type"
//Then sum the Count column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(filter, {"Component", "Type"}, 
        {{"Count", each List.Sum([Count]), type nullable number}})
        
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: That was a perfect formula I was looking for. Also I have tried Power Query with M code for the first time and it works perfect as well. Thanks a lot!